# Testing an expression evaluator in Go

Tags: go

I have written a small constant number expression evaluator. I’m running go-fuzz on it, but it can only detect crashes.

I would like to test that expression considered invalid by my program are really invalid, and valid expression are really valid and yield a correct result.

How could I do that in Go ?

I looked into existing packages like [this one](https://github.com/PaesslerAG/gval), but it allows much more operations and types than I currently support. It thus can’t use it for validation.

The values that I handle are int and float64, and the operations are | & ^  ~(inverse) + - * /  %. Also I support the same type of number literals as Go.

I did manual checks but this doesn’t bring me very far. I would need to check the result against another expression evaluator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`go/types`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/) and co.:

> Constant folding computes the exact constant value (constant.Value)
> for every expression (ast.Expr) that is a compile-time constant. Use
> Info.Types[expr].Value for the results of constant folding.

<sup>I'll use `Info.Defs` instead of `Info.Types` as that's simpler for this case, IMO at least.</sup>

```golang
expr := "float64(20)/6.8"

// parse the expression as part of a file so that it can be type checked
fset := token.NewFileSet()
f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "x.go", "package x\nconst K = "+expr, 0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// type check the file so that the constant value gets computed
info := types.Info{Defs: map[*ast.Ident]types.Object{}}
conf := types.Config{}
if _, err := conf.Check("x", fset, []*ast.File{f}, &info); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// get the value (as string)
for id, obj := range info.Defs {
    if id.Name == "K" {
        v := obj.(*types.Const).Val()
        fmt.Println(v.String())
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/h2e0No2F1CY